# Angular 4 - Testing when a component has another component

Tags: angular

I am applying testing to my application of Angular:

```
ng test
```

This is my html file (page-not-found.component.html):

```
<menu></menu>
<div>
  <h4>
    ERROR 404 - PÁGINA NO ENCONTRADA
  </h4>
</div>
```

When I run ng test the  component gives me error.

This the file spec (page-not-found.component.spec.ts)

```
import { MenuComponent } from '../menu/menu.component';

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ PageNotFoundComponent, MenuComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

This is the component code (pàge-not-found.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-not-found',
  templateUrl: './page-not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-not-found.component.css']
})
export class PageNotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is the error:

```
Error: No provider for ActivatedRoute!
```

Could you tell me the problem? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a provider for ActivatedRoute in your Testbed. For example

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ PageNotFoundComponent, MenuComponent ],
providers: [
        {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRoute}, // using a mock
      ]
    })
```

Does that menucomponent needs te be in your not-found component?

Comment: Yes, is necessary, it is the header, I am going to test and I comment you, thanks

Comment: But I do not understand this practice well, because menu is a component, but it does not have any route in my angular routes file

Comment: It is working ok, I have created a file ts mock (activated-route.ts), but I don't undestand Why? I need this file to can to test the header component (MenuComponent) inside to html of component PageNotFoundComponent, i will search more documentation

Comment: The menucomponent is injecting ActivatedRoute in the constructor.